# reprex setting output width

Tags: r, tidyverse, reprex

How do I set the width of a reprex output?

Say I have a code like this:

```
(x <- 1:100)
```

I get this with `reprex::reprex(venue = "so")`

```
(x <- 1:100)
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
#>  [18]  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
#>  [35]  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
#>  [52]  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68
#>  [69]  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85
#>  [86]  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

How can I increase the width of the output to output something like this

```
 [1]    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
 [51]  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

### Possible Solutions

One option that I have found but I find rather "un-tidy" is this (include `options(width = ...)` at the top of the code. But I don't want it to show up in the output, I'd prefer setting the width in the reprex-call.

```
options(width = 205)
(x <- 1:100)
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
#>  [51]  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

`reprex()` allows for knitr's `opts-chunk`, but I can't get it working with `reprex::reprex(venue = "so", opts_chunk = list(out.width = 205))` (which might be related to [#421](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/421) as pointed out [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/) (Long lines of text output))

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reprex` has a syntax for setting these options but not including them in the output markdown (see [here](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/reference/reprex.html) for examples). In this case:

```r
reprex({

  #+ setup, include = FALSE
  options(width=205)

  #+ actual-reprex-code
  (x <- 1:100)

}, venue = 'so')
```

outputs your desired format:

```r
(x <- 1:100)
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
#>  [51]  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>